# Comparison of integers of different signs warning with Xcode

Tags: xcode, configuration, build

I use an open source to build my project. when I add `EGOTextView` to the project, it has Semantic Issues like:

```
Comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')
Comparison of integers of different signs: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') and 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long')
```

For example in source code:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < lines.count; i++)//lines is an array
```

I notice the project has build configure file which includes:

```
// Make CG and NS geometry types be the same. Mostly doesn't matter on iPhone, but this also makes NSInteger types be defined based on 'long' consistently, which avoids conflicting warnings from clang + llvm 2.7 about printf format checking

OTHER_CFLAGS = $(value) -DNS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
```

According to the comments, I guess it causes the problems.
However, I don't know the meaning for this `OTHER_CFLAGS` setting. And I also don't know how to fix it so that it can avoid the semantic issues.

Could any one help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configuration option you're looking at won't do anything about the warning you quoted. What you need to do is go into your build settings and search for the "sign comparison" warning. Turn that off.

[image]

Comment: Instead of turning off warnings, how about fixing the bug? See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20543204/172218) below.

Comment: If the file producing the warning is from an external lib, use the `-w` flag on the file instead. It will silence warnings on the file, but not on the rest of your project.

Answer (score 26):

Actually, I don't think turning off the compiler warning is the right solution, since comparing an `int` and an `unsigned long` introduces a subtle bug.

For example:

```
unsigned int a = UINT_MAX; // 0xFFFFFFFFU == 4,294,967,295 
signed int b = a; // 0xFFFFFFFF == -1

for (int i = 0; i < b; ++i)
{
    // the loop will have zero iterations because i < b is always false!
}
```

Basically if you simply cast away (implicitly or explicitly) an `unsigned int` to an `int` your code will behave incorrectly if the value of your `unsigned int` is greater than INT_MAX.

The correct solution is to cast the `signed int` to `unsigned int` and to also compare the `signed int` to zero, covering the case where it is negative:

```
unsigned int a = UINT_MAX; // 0xFFFFFFFFU == 4,294,967,295 

for (int i = 0; i < 0 || (unsigned)i < a; ++i)
{
    // The loop will have UINT_MAX iterations
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of doing all of this strange type casting all over the place, you ought to first notice why you are comparing different types in the first place: YOU ARE CREATING AN INT!!

do this instead:

```
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < lines.count; i++)//lines is an array
```

...and now you are comparing the same types!

Comment: Something like this was suggested in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12400226/27678

OP is likely using `int i` for something, so we don't know for certain whether it's a good idea to just change its type altogether. In all likelihood they can; we just don't know though.

Comment: @AndyG This was NOT suggested above.  [link](stackoverflow.com/a/12400226/27678) uses an implicit type cast (worse than the originally exposited explicit dynamic typecast which has runtime checking and is clear to read and sticks out while skimming code) to change the type.  It is clear that the OP is simply iterating over an array from the original question: unsigned i is appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of turning the warnings of you can also prevent them from occurring.

Your lines.count is of type NSUInteger. Make an int of this first, and then do the comparison:

```
int count = lines.count;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
```

Comment: This just disguises the bug the compiler is warning the OP about, it doesn't fix it. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20543204/172218) for an explanation why.